# Validating Weka Multilayer Perceptron in Rapidminer

Tags: neural-network, data-mining, weka, rapidminer

I was trying to implement the W-Multilayer Perceptron from the Weka Rapidminer plugin. When I run it in my dataset it takes around 1.5 hours to finish training a simple 5 layer perceptron.

However although the Perceptron itself seem to be working properly when I put it on the validation operator, it gets stuck in the validation phase consuming more and more memory. I left it running during the night and it has been there for 15 hours. To me it doesn't make sense since after creating the mode, applying it shouldn't take nearly so much time. Does anyone who understood the workings of this can tell me what's happening?

The way I am using the operator is the following, in my scheme it's directly connected to a read database operator with only the set role operator between them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.008">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="split_validation" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="112" name="Validation (6)" width="90" x="45" y="120">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="weka:W-MultilayerPerceptron" compatibility="5.3.001" expanded="true" height="76" name="W-MultilayerPerceptron" width="90" x="69" y="30">
            <parameter key="N" value="100.0"/>
            <parameter key="S" value="30.0"/>
            <parameter key="H" value="5"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="training" to_op="W-MultilayerPerceptron" to_port="training set"/>
          <connect from_op="W-MultilayerPerceptron" from_port="model" to_port="model"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_training" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_through 1" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Apply Model (6)" width="90" x="45" y="30">
            <list key="application_parameters"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="performance" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Performance (6)" width="90" x="147" y="30"/>
          <connect from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model (6)" to_port="model"/>
          <connect from_port="test set" to_op="Apply Model (6)" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Apply Model (6)" from_port="labelled data" to_op="Performance (6)" to_port="labelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Performance (6)" from_port="performance" to_port="averagable 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_test set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_through 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: How many examples are there in the data set read from the database? What happens to the timings if you sample a much smaller fraction of these (use the `Sample` operator) and then gradually increase the number while observing the time? Does the time increase linearly with the number of examples?

Comment: Testing with 2000 examples, can't say about if it increases since I ended up shifting to the rapidminer's MP due to this issue.